# Password encrypted in slapd.conf-File

Tags: authentication, openldap, password-encryption, password-hash

I have set up an OpenLDAP service with the slapd.conf file.

Everything is working find, but the customer wants to have the password encrypted in the slapd.conf-file and I'm struggeling to implement this it.

It works with this line:

```
idassert-bind bindmethod=simple binddn=CN=ldap-openLDAP,OU=Services,OU=company,DC=example,DC=com credentials=123456 mode=self
```

But the customer doesn't want to have the credentials of the user as plain text in the config file. Is there a way to write an encrypted password like e.g.:

```
idassert-bind bindmethod=simple binddn=CN=ldap-openLDAP,OU=Services,OU=company,DC=example,DC=com credentials={SHA256}asa78asadASf mode=self
```

I already found out that with simple bind only plain text passwords are possible.
The alternative is bindmethod=sasl. But with this I have to decide where I want to do the authentication with Kerberos or GSSAPI.
I'm not that familiar with this authentication methods.

Is there a way to store the password encrypted in the slapd.conf? If not, what exactly do I have to do to make the authentication to the LDAP-Server?

I installed OpenLDAP on a Windows Server (not UNIX). Because all the tutorials I found seem to be made for Linux-Servers.

Answer (score 1):

`{SHA256}asa78asadASf` is a **password hash**. Hashing is (designed to be) one-way; there is (should be) no way to get back the original password `123456` from that.

At this time there is no support for encrypting credentials stored in slapd.conf.

For an easier solution than Kerberos, you might consider TLS client certificates. You can easily create your own CA certificate and issue a couple of client certificates from it. But note that this isn't any more secure than a plaintext password in slapd.conf! slapd has to be able to access the credentials it's supposed to present; anyone who can read the slapd.conf file can then obviously read those credentials as well, whether it's a plaintext password, a Kerberos keytab, or a certificate private key.